# ExtJS 4 Center text in 'box' element

Tags: extjs, extjs4

In my interface I use the following structure:

```
xtype: 'container',
layout: {
    type: 'hbox',
    align: 'stretch'
},
items: [
{
    xtype: 'fieldset',
    flex: 2,
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },
    margin: '0 5 0 0',
    padding: '10',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            flex: 1,
            layout: 'hbox',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'combo',
                    flex: 1,
                    margin: '0 5 0 0',
                    name: 'deviceSelect',
                    ...
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    ...
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    ...
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'box',
            flex: 1,
            name: 'deviceMessage'
            ...
        }
    ]
},
{
    ...
},
{
    ...
}
```

Combo 'deviceSelect' should take entire width of the container except of the size of the two buttons and under it should be text. At the moment everything is working as it should, with one exception - the text "pinned" to the top of its 'deviceMessage' container. How can place it in the middle (vertically) of the container? I tried style: 'vertical-align: middle;', but it doesnt work (probably because ext add top: 24px).

I think the code is not optimal. Any comments are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/laurenzonneveld/YLrzC/?

The part you need is the `layout` part:

```
xtype: 'container',
name: 'deviceMessage',
layout: {
    // Centers your inner panel with the HTML
    type: 'vbox',
    align: 'center',
    pack: 'center'
},
//...
items: {
    xtype: 'container',
    html: 'sadfasdf<br>safasdfasf'
}
```